# bug with regular collisions in spriteKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit

Im making a very simple jumping game. When my "hero" collides with the ground it calls `didBeginContact` and make a jump. Pretty basic but it doesn't work well because after a while (sometimes sooner, sometimes later...) it stop working as you can see. I would like to know if Im doing something wrong or if there is a better way to do it, or if there is a known bug in spriteKit Id never heard of...
The image is a gif. If can't see movement open it in a new tab
[image: jumping secuence]

```
@interface XYZWorld1()
@property (nonatomic)  SKSpriteNode *hero;
@property (nonatomic) SKSpriteNode *groundPhysics;
@end


@implementation XYZWorld1
static const uint32_t ground = 0x2 << 2;
static const uint32_t bee = 0x3 << 3;
```

Method to create the ground:

```
    -(SKSpriteNode*)createGroundxPos:(float)x yPos:(float)y width:(CGFloat)width height:(CGFloat)height
{
    SKSpriteNode *ground = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor colorWithHue:1 saturation:1 brightness:1 alpha:1] size:CGSizeMake(width, height)];
    SKPhysicsBody *groundFisica =[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:ground.size];
    [ground setName:@"ground"];
    [groundFisica setDynamic:NO];
    [groundFisica setAffectedByGravity:NO];
    [groundFisica setAllowsRotation:NO];
    [groundFisica setRestitution:0];
    [groundFisica setUsesPreciseCollisionDetection:YES];
    [groundFisica setCategoryBitMask:ground];
    [groundFisica setContactTestBitMask:bee];
    [groundFisica setCollisionBitMask:bee];
    ground.physicsBody = groundFisica;
    [ground setPosition:CGPointMake(x, y)];
    return ground;

}
```

Method to create hero

```
-(SKSpriteNode*)crearHero
{
    SKTexture *temp = _heroWalkingFrames[0];
    SKSpriteNode *hero = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:temp];

    hero.name = @"hero";
    hero.zPosition = 1;
    if(IS_IPHONE_5){
        [hero setPosition:CGPointMake(100, 280)];
    }
    else {
        [hero setPosition:CGPointMake(100, 220)];
    }

    [hero setSize:CGSizeMake(25, 25)];
    hero.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(23, 24)];

    [hero.physicsBody setDensity:0.95];
    [hero.physicsBody setDynamic:YES];
    [hero.physicsBody setAffectedByGravity:YES];
    [hero.physicsBody setAllowsRotation:NO];
    [hero.physicsBody setUsesPreciseCollisionDetection:YES];
    [hero.physicsBody setRestitution:0];
    [hero.physicsBody setVelocity:CGVectorMake(0, 0)];
    return hero;
}
```

Method to preload all the stuff before the game starts:

```
-(void)preloadAssets
{
    //hero
    _heroWalkingFrames = [self cargarArrayAtlas:@"astroJump.atlas" imageName:@"astronautaJump_000"];
    _hero = [self crearHero];

    _hero.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = bee;
    _hero.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = bee | cubico | ground | bicho ;
    _hero.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = bee | cubico | ground | bicho  ;


//Ground
_groundPhysics = [self createGroundxPos:100 yPos:142 width:42 height:23.25];
}
```

Method called when two bodies first contact each other:

```
-(void) didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact 
{
    //if hero collides with ground

    if((contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == bee && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ground) ||
       (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ground && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == bee) )
    {

        if(_jumping == NO && _groundPhysics.position.y+_groundPhysics.size.height/2<=_hero.position.y-11.5)
        {

            [self jumping];
        }
    }
}
```

Method called to do the jump:

```
-(void)jumping{
    //Play sound file
    [self runAction:self.jumpSound withKey:@"jumpSound"];


    if(IS_IPHONE_5){
        _diferencia=(164 * 9)/_hero.position.y;

    }else{
        _diferencia=(164 * 7)/_hero.position.y;
    }


    [_hero.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(0,_diferencia)];
    _jumping = YES;
    [_hero removeActionForKey:@"astroJump"];
    [self astroJump];
}

-(void)astroJump
{
    //runAction animation method
    [_hero runAction:[SKAction animateWithTextures:_heroWalkingFrames
                                       timePerFrame:0.05f
                                             resize:NO
                                            restore:NO] withKey:@"astroJump"];
    return;
}
```

the boolean (self.jumping) from the if sentence, in `update` and `initGameContent`:

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime
{
if(_hero.physicsBody.velocity.dy < 0 )_jumping = NO;
}

-(void)initGameContent
{

    _jumping = NO;
```

Comment: I don't like this line `[groundFisica setRestitution:-10];` To start, restitution must be positive, between 0 and 1.

Comment: True. I hadn't noticed that line... I've set it to 0 and tryed again but the bug remains... I've also edited code here

Comment: I would try setting your _jumping BOOL to NO in the didEndContact:

Comment: Tried this solution too but still the same result..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to fix it. I've changed the size of `physicbody.size.y` to the same as his spriteNode.y and the bug has gone.

Comment: There is no `size` property in `SKPhysicsBody`.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to make sure you reset your players position to be above the ground when contact with the ground is detected. Otherwise the player could still be in contact with the ground when `[self jumping];` is called which can sometimes result in the player being "stuck". I've seen similar issues in my games when doing collision detection. The code below shows what you could do to resolve this issue.

```
if (_jumping == NO && _groundPhysics.position.y+_groundPhysics.size.height/2<=_hero.position.y-11.5)
{
    _hero.position.y = _groundPhysics.position.y + _groundPhysics.size.height/2 + 1;
    [self jumping];
}
```

Comment: It's a very good tip thanks, and I will use this technique for avoid multiple collisions, now I can remove my bool (_jumping) but my problem is a bit diferent because it's an undetected collision so my code in "didBeginContact" is not executed when this bug happen. In any case thanks a lot, it was usefull